# How to merge two arrays of objects based on the same date

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

> Actually, i want to merge all the products with the same date into the same object as below, i tried lot of algorithms but it doesn't work so that's why i published this post. You can find an example of the data and the expected result.

```
let obj = {}; for(let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++){ let date = this.data[i].Date; let p_date = obj[date] || {}; obj[date] = Object.assign(p_date, this.data[i]); } let result = Object.values(obj); return result; 


  this.data = [
                      {
                        "Date": "12/06/2019",
                        "Rank": 1,
                        "ASIN": "B01N9J7MLI",
                        "Rating": "4,1",
                        "Reviews": 4592,
                        "Price": "114,99",
                        "Prime": "No"
                      },
                      {
                        "Date": "12/06/2019",
                        "Rank": 2,
                        "ASIN": "B074QXGBG6",
                        "Rating": 4,
                        "Reviews": 29163,
                        "Price": "60,99",
                        "Prime": "No"
                      }];
```

**expected result :**

```
 this.data = {
                "Date": "12/06/2019",
                "Products": [
                {
                "Date": "12/06/2019",
                "Rank": 1,
                "ASIN": "B01N9J7MLI",
                "Rating": "4,1",
                "Reviews": 4592,
                "Price": "114,99",
                "Prime": "No"
              },
              {
                "Date": "12/06/2019",
                "Rank": 2,
                "ASIN": "B074QXGBG6",
                "Rating": 4,
                "Reviews": 29163,
                "Price": "60,99",
                "Prime": "No"
              }
                ],
              }
```

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Please show the effort you made to solve this problem yourself. Doing so will increase your chances of getting help here.

Comment: @Yousaf 

`let obj = {}; for(let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++){ let date = this.data[i].Date; let p_date = obj[date] || {}; obj[date] = Object.assign(p_date, this.data[i]); } let result = Object.values(obj); return result; `

Comment: You can edit your question to include the code you tried in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to accumulate your data to an object with properties for the dates. Foreach object look if in the accumulated object exists a property with this date. If not create it with properties date and Products (with an empty array). In both cases add to this array your current object.
At the end use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get the valuesfrom your object to get the desired array.

```js
  this.data = [
    {
      "Date": "12/06/2019",
      "Rank": 1,
      "ASIN": "B01N9J7MLI",
      "Rating": "4,1",
      "Reviews": 4592,
      "Price": "114,99",
      "Prime": "No"
    },
    {
      "Date": "12/06/2019",
      "Rank": 2,
      "ASIN": "B074QXGBG6",
      "Rating": 4,
      "Reviews": 29163,
      "Price": "60,99",
      "Prime": "No"
    }];
    
    let res = Object.values(this.data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        if (!acc[cur.Date])
            acc[cur.Date] = {Date: cur.Date, Products: []};
        acc[cur.Date].Products.push(cur);
        return acc;
    }, {}));
    
    console.log(res);
```